# Вывод в форму результата работы функции в js

Tags: javascript

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Результаты вычислений</legend>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="outputvalue" value="" placeholder="Вывод    данных">
    </p>   
    <p>
      <button type="reset">Сброс</button>  
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let keys = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Thu', 'Wen', 'The', 'Fry', 'Sat'];
    let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    let obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i <=6; i++) {
      obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
    }
    console.log(obj);
    document.getElementById('outputvalue').value = ?;
</script>
```

Прошу прощения за тупость, но может найдётся кто нибудь, кто подскажет чайнику как вывести результаты (obj) в форму? Мне не важен конкретный пример -- хотелось бы понять как выводить подобное в формы. В консоль выводится. Если указываю значения переменных(keys или values) -- выводится.

Answer (score 1):

То есть Вы хотите выдать в текстовое поле с id="outputvalue" обьект? Ну в таком случае его необходимо сериализовать или как-то иначе представить строкой.

Попробуйте:

```
document.getElementById('outputvalue').value = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

Comment: О, вот это по делу, кажись -- щас буду пробовать.

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответы, сумерки разума временные -- преобразование затупил.

Comment: Всегда рад! Вот тебе ещё для просветления)
https://learn.javascript.ru/

Comment: Дык курю всё это самоэ. Благодарсвую, болярин.

Comment: @user366066 я дописал свой ответ, возможно вам станет яснее

Answer (score 0):

Это имеете ввиду?

```js
let keys = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Thu', 'Wen', 'The', 'Fry', 'Sat'];
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
}
document.getElementById('outputvalue').value = obj['Sun'];
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Результаты вычислений</legend>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="outputvalue" value="" placeholder="Вывод    данных">
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="reset">Сброс</button>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Вы можете запоминать значение дня недели из массива и записывать это в переменную и передать в `input`

```js
let keys = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Thu', 'Wen', 'The', 'Fry', 'Sat'];
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

let day = keys[1]; // значение, которое можно считать в программе

document.getElementById('outputvalue').value = obj[day];
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Результаты вычислений</legend>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="outputvalue" value="" placeholder="Вывод    данных">
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="reset">Сброс</button>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Также вы можете передать день недели в input, с помощью `Object.keys(obj)`, чтобы узнать имя элемента в объекте, в данном примере переменная `num = 1`, выводится второй элемент **массива** `Object.keys(obj)`, который начинается с нуля

```js
let keys = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Thu', 'Wen', 'The', 'Fry', 'Sat'];
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
  obj[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

let num = 1; // значение, которое можно считать в программе

document.getElementById('outputvalue').value = Object.keys(obj)[num];
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Результаты вычислений</legend>
    <p>
      <input type="text" id="outputvalue" value="" placeholder="Вывод    данных">
    </p>
    <p>
      <button type="reset">Сброс</button>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Я так понял вы выводите в консоль. В консоль то это всё выводится. А вот как объект склеенный из двух массивов вывести? В форму.

Comment: @user366066 убрал вывод в консоль, в input выводится значение цифры в массиве, если вы хотите, чтобы в input выводилось название месяца, переформулируйте вопрос